# Trigger Microsft flow mutilpe emails

Tags: flow, microsoft-flow

I have a requirement to trigger a same flow for multiple emails For example, I have a 50 emails (Outlook or Office 365 account). I want to build a flow which should be triggered when the user sends an email to any email which is from my 50 email list

Answer (score 0):

In Flow doesn't exist any trigred for "*When email was sent*" but there are "*When a new email arrives*" maybe you can create flow based on this? I don't know deeper logic of your Flow.

[image]